# What is the purpose of papillote on lamb bones?

Tags: french-cuisine, lamb, bones, decorating

Is it just for decoration, or does it serve a purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the little paper frills on the ends of the bones on a Frenched rack of lamb, those are purely decorative.

[image]

Comment: ...and ridiculously fussy.